StripeJS - CSP error: Refused to create a worker from 'blob:' URL due to missing 'worker-src' directive
I’m encountering an issue related to Content Security Policy (CSP) and Web Workers when integrating the Stripe API in my local project.
Problem description:
When I try to load the page that integrates Stripe.js, I get the following error in the console:
Refused to create a worker from 'blob:https://m.stripe.network/9ebe38a1-64c4-425e-835f-e4af76e27553' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src https://m.stripe.network 'sha256-/5Guo2nzv5n/w6ukZpOBZOtTJBJPSkJ6mhHpnBgm3Ls='". Note that 'worker-src' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

The error indicates that Stripe is attempting to create a Web Worker from a blob: URL, but it is being blocked by the page’s Content Security Policy (CSP).
What I've tried so far:
I have updated the CSP policy in my HTML code, specifically in the worker-src directive, to allow blob: URLs. Here’s the version of CSP I’m using:
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src *; style-src *; img-src *; font-src *; connect-src *; frame-src *; object-src *; child-src *; media-src *; manifest-src *; worker-src * blob:;">

Even though the worker-src * blob: directive is included, I’m still seeing the same error.
This is how my code looks so far:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
        content="default-src * blob:; script-src *; style-src *; img-src *; font-src *; connect-src *; frame-src *; object-src *; child-src *; media-src *; manifest-src *; worker-src * blob:;">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

    <title>Stripe Integration - Proof of Concept</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="">
        <label for="">Label</label>
        <input type="text" name="" id="">
    </form>
    <script>
        const stripe = Stripe('pk_test_---'); 
    </script>
</body>

</html>

Why I believe this is a CSP issue:
The error message suggests that the problem is related to the lack of a proper CSP directive that allows the creation of Web Workers from blob: URLs.
What I've tried:

Added blob: to the worker-src directive in CSP.
Tried allowing * for all sources in the CSP (e.g., script-src *).
I’ve read about how blob: URLs need to be explicitly allowed in the CSP, and I’ve followed the suggestions from the official documentation, but the error persists.

What I’m looking for:
I would appreciate any guidance on whether I’ve missed any steps or if there’s a more effective way to allow blob: Web Workers in a content security policy, in a secure manner.
Has anyone faced this issue before, or does anyone know how to resolve it?
Thanks in advance for any help.
Additional details:

Stripe.js Version: I am using the latest version of Stripe.js.
Environment: Local development using an HTTP server at 127.0.0.1:5500


Have you checked whether your server / system specifies a CSP via the HTTP response headers already, perhaps? Because "I have updated the CSP policy in my HTML code" won't do you any good, if a more restrictive CSP has already been set via the headers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy#multiple_content_security_policies: "Adding additional policies can only further restrict the capabilities of the protected resource"

@C3roe I've tested this in two different environments: locally and on a site hosted with cPanel. Neither environment has any specific CSP restrictions in place, as there’s no CSP configuration in the .htaccess file. I can successfully import scripts from a variety of endpoints without issues, but the Stripe script is the only one causing problems.

These are the CSP directives that Stripe.js requires https://docs.stripe.com/security/guide?csp=csp-js#content-security-policy
Can you add them to your integration and try again?

Still not working :(
